# 128 character limit in Drupal text fields

Tags: forms

I maintain a small module on Drupal.org and I'm having a few problems fixing this issue:

http://drupal.org/node/917340

Is this limit of 128 characters imposed by Drupal Core? Can I do anything in my module's code to work around this limit? Or is it best to suggest that users of my module use something like http://drupal.org/project/maxlength or http://drupal.org/project/skip_validation?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe my brain isn't in gear, but in your code you have `'#maxlength' => 128,` everywhere...  Changing that to 4096 worked here and allowed a really long message. Changing `textfield` to `textarea` and removing `#size` and `#maxlength` worked as well.